# Add authentication data to firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase at a school project and I'm having the same problem a while... I have looked at various sites but I can't find anyone with the same problem...

The User authentication is working correctly, but the problem is with saving the user data in the database.
I have two available ways to authenticate:

- Email and password;
- Facebook.

With email and password, the data is written successfully in the database, and I'm using the following JavaScript code:

```js
function signUp(){
    //Get DOM data
    const email = String(document.getElementById('TXTEmail').value);
    const pass = String(document.getElementById('TXTPassword').value);
    const name = String(document.getElementById('TXTNome').value);
    const gender = document.registo.sexo.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    var promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

    firebase.database().ref('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set({
        name : name,
        email : email,
        gender : gender,
        uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    });
}
```

However, when using the function of facebook I can't save the data, I can only authenticate the user, and the code I'm using is as follows:

```js
function signUpFacebook(){
        var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
        firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
        firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
            if (result.credential) {
                // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
                var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            }
            // The signed-in user info.
            var user = result.user;
            const name = user.displayName;
            const email = user.email;
            const photo = user.photoURL;
            if(user != 0) {
                firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set({
                    name: nome,
                    email: email,
                    photo: photo,
                    uid: user.uid
                });
            }
            //Tests only
            if(user != 0){
                console.log("name: "+user.displayName);
                console.log("email: "+user.email);
                console.log("photoUrl: "+user.photoURL);
                console.log("uid: "+user.uid);
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // The email of the user's account used.
            var email = error.email;
            // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
            var credential = error.credential;

        });
    }
```

And I get this output on my console:
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH6by.png).

```
name: Rafael Veloso 
email: rafael****@gmail.com 
photoUrl: scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/s100x100/… 
uid: **HY43Tl******KoO6OhZjG****
```

Also, my database.rules.json is:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what is the problem that I'm having?
Thank you.

Comment: Please post the console output as actual text, not as a picture. There are good reasons why you're not allowed to post pictures yet, and this is one of them.

Comment: Sorry @FrankvanPuffelen, the output is:
name: Rafael Veloso
email: rafael****@gmail.com
photoUrl: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/s100x100/13139253_951385514977558_8691565872507444364_n.jpg?oh=51b7c82e907fdfa411ccaf3c58afe224&oe=58904789
uid: **HY43Tl******KoO6OhZjG*****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the help of the Firebase support I managed to solve my problem :)

First, created a script within the .html document like that:

```js
<script>
document.getElementById('btnFacebook').addEventListener('click', signUpFacebook, false);

function signUpFacebook(){
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
}

function createNewPost(name, email, photo, uid) {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid).set({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        photo: photo,
        uid: uid
    });
}

firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
    if (result.credential) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    }
    // The signed-in user info.
    if(user != null) {
        console.log("name: "+user.displayName);
        console.log("email: "+user.email);
        console.log("photoUrl: "+user.photoURL);
        console.log("uid: "+user.uid);
    }

}).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    var email = error.email;
    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
    var credential = error.credential;

});

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        var name = user.displayName;
        var email = user.email;
        var photo = user.photoURL;
        var uid = user.uid;
        createNewPost(name, email, photo, uid);
        console.log("name: "+user.displayName);
        console.log("email: "+user.email);
        console.log("photoUrl: "+user.photoURL);
        console.log("uid: "+user.uid);
    }
});
```

With just that, I still wasn't able to add the user data to the Realtime Database, so I changed my "imports", I was with this:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
```

and only when I changed to the following I was able to save the user data in the Database:

```
<!--    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
```

But I find that strange, can anyone help and explain me why that worked out?